# Ficheros tras instalación Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

En una ***instalación limpia de Laravel 5.7.*** puede encontrarse el fichero ***"public/js/app.js"*** con bastante código.

¿Cuál es el uso inicial o previsto para ese código?

Answer (score 0):

Desde Laravel 5.3.0 se incluyen los assets «predeterminados» previamente compilados, más exactamente desde agosto de 2016.

Al respecto nunca ha habido un pronunciamiento oficial por parte de Taylor Otwell (creador de Laravel) ni por parte de ninguno de sus colaboradores, sin embargo en la comunidad Laravel se ha asumido que dicho archivo se incluye compilado con el fin de ofrecer un ambiente de front-end listo para que una persona novata en la programación o en Laravel pueda crear algo rápidamente sin preocuparse por entender el primer día como usar Webpack, Sass, Vue o cualquiera de los elementos ajenos al framework Laravel.

En el commit respectivo de los assets compilados (23 de julio de 2016) tan solo hay un tímido comentario de alguien que ha contribuido a Laravel, y que refleja la opinión de muchos de la comunidad, aquellos quienes consideramos que esta es una mala práctica porque da la impresión a los principiantes que es correcto incluir en git los archivos compilados.

Enlace al commit respectivo y al comentario: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/592b7a2bd9452def0458bf2b41bd5f6cfca27f55#comments